# Runnable Jar can't find a resource even if the path is defined in the classpath in the manifest

Tags: java, jar

I created a runnable jar but when I run it with:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

The file is in the folder resources. So I used winzip to modify my manifest adding the resource dir in that way:

```
Class-Path: . ./resources
```

But I still get the same error.

What I've done wrong? What should I do instead?

Comment: does this file exist in jar ?

Comment: Is the Class-Path value "../resources" or ". ./resources"?

Comment: Yes, the file exist in resources.  It's with the space in the manifest: . ./resources

Answer (score 0):

As per [this dude](http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.com/2011/03/jar-manifestmf-class-path-referencing.html) class directories must end in a /.  So use `./resources/`